# Authentication user across two subdomains without a common auth server - 2

Tags: security, authentication, single-sign-on, subdomain

I have a running server say foo.com which uses its own private database for authentication and I have another server x.foo.com so as to get the foo.com's cookie information.

Now I want the user to be authenticated to x.foo.com only when he is login to foo.com. We don't have an oauth server and I don't wish to access foo from x.foo .

Is there any way of achieving SSO without a common AUTH Server and without any interaction between the two servers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid interaction between the two servers, you will need to put all the user info x.foo.com needs into the cookie and add a signature to it so that x.foo.com can verify that the user didn't change the contents of the cookie.

foo.com and x.foo.com must be configured with the same secret token.

E.g. the user info could look like this: `user-info = "<user-id>:<username>:<login-time>"`.

To create a signature, you can use a hashing algorithm like SHA1, `signature = sha1("<user-info><secret-key>")`

And set the cookie to `"<user-info>:<signature>"`.

x.foo.com then can take the the `user-info` part, generate the signature from the same way and verify that the signature matches.

The user will still be able to read the contents of the cookie, but not modify it, so they can't fake a login. Make sure you have a timestamp and check that it's fairly recent, so an attacker couldn't use an old cookie to gain access to x.foo.com.

If the user-info contains secret info then you should also encrypt the contents.